# Difference between data and json parameters in Python Requests package

Tags: python, json, python-requests

What is the difference between the `data` and `json` parameters in the Python Requests package?

It is unclear from [the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/).

Does this code:

```
import requests
import json
d = {'a': 1}
response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(d))
```

( **note that we convert the `dict` to JSON here ☝️ !** )

... do anything different than:

```
import requests
import json
d = {'a': 1}
response = requests.post(url, json=d)
```

If so, what?

Does the latter automatically set the `Content-Type` HTTP header to `application/json`?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

To answer my own question, it appears my two examples above do the same thing and that using the `json` parameter does indeed set the `content-type` in the headers to `application/json`.  In my first example above using the `data` parameter, the `content-type` in the headers would need to be set manually.

Comment: This behaves like an API should behave. You can look that up here https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L422 as well.

Comment: Agreed, just wasn't documented anywhere without actually reading the code.

Comment: This is indeed sane behavior, but it would be helpful to properly document it. `json=data` with data being a dict is not necessarily obvious. My first instinct was `json=json.dumps(data)` because it felt more accurate. Then I got unrelated errors on the remote API's end, because it was receiving the result of a json string further encoded in json (i.e. double dumped). Difficult to detect since it's a simple string and thus still valid json. To add to the confusion, when logging what the receiving end obtained, the output is indistinguishable whether in string or dict form.

Comment: Updating the earlier requests code link to [this](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L465).

Comment: Data in the body payload is not serialised to a string in the same way for the two cases, irrespective to the header differences. Other answers explain the difference and provide a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 89):

As of **Dec 2021** the `requests` [documentation about using `data` vs `json`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) is now pretty clear about the difference.

(With our small contribution to it - [my PR](https://github.com/psf/requests/pull/5382) and your upvotes that confirmed that this used to be an issue. Thank you!).

---

### P.S.

This does NOT answer the OP question but if the FIRST piece of code would be a bit different:

```
import requests
import json
d = {'a': 1}
response = requests.post(url, data=d)
```

(note that the `dict` `d` is **NOT** converted to JSON string here!)

And if the second code would be the same (copying it for completeness):

```
import requests
import json
d = {'a': 1}
response = requests.post(url, json=d)
```

...then the result would be quite a lot different.

First code would generate a request with content type set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and the data in this format, so: `"a=1"`

The second code would generate a request with content type set to `application/json` and in fact the data in this format, so `{"a": 1}` - a JSON string.

Comment: I came across this situation in a test scenario, the json param was passing tests - stripping it made sure we tested the payload as it would if it was passed like the data param. 

loads(request.data.strip(b'"'))

Thanks for the contribution!

Comment: To add on to what Greg said, if the `data` param is supplied a string instead of a dict, like the OP did in their first code above (`response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(d))`) then, instead of defaulting the content type header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, it doesn't appear to generate any default content type header, as per [this code](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/95f456733656ed93645ff0250bfa54f6d256f6fe/requests/models.py#L522-L527).

Comment: As of this moment, python-requests.org is not working. The documentation is also available at https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Comment: Thanks @Jimothy, I updated the URL in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Talking only from my experience here, but please note that it should be preferred to use the `json` field with the dict, rather than dumping the dict in the `data` field.

Again, talking only from experience, I did not study the code itself, but it seems that the requests library does some more clever json serialization than just `json.dumps`. When using `json.dumps` in `data` field, I have encountered several instances where this resulted in an "value is not a valid dict" error response from the (FastAPI) server. Using the `json` field instead fixed these issues.

EDIT: I went through the code today. If you use the `json` parameter, it seems the requests library really only sets `Content-Type` and dumps it:

```python
from .compat import json as complexjson
content_type = 'application/json'
body = complexjson.dumps(json)
if not isinstance(body, bytes):
    body = body.encode('utf-8')
```

where in the `requests.compat`, the `json` is just:

```python
try:
    import simplejson as json
except ImportError:
    import json
```

... therefore I really cannot figure out why doing this manually using the `data` parameter just sometimes fails to work. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯