# Elasticsearch bulk index "mapper_parsing_exception"

Tags: elasticsearch, jq

I am trying to bulk index using jq, and having trouble.

I enter the following using the terminal (I'm using Ubuntu 16.04)

```
cat practice.json | jq -c '.[] | {"index": {"_index": "text", "_type": "text", "_id": "text"}}, .' | curl -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @-
```

This is the error that I get:

```
{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse","caused_by":{"type":"not_x_content_exception","reason":"not_x_content_exception: Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"}}}}
```

Oddly, I was able to get similar code (I forgot to save what I did, but I think it is the same as this) to work. I couldn't find anyone with the same problem here or elsewhere. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you please inform the content of your practice.json?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an issue with the document sent to jq. ElasticSearch requires the outermost document to be a JSON object and not a JSON array or scalar value. Just make sure it is...

Check this out: [ElasticSearch error while sending data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213472/elasticsearch-error-while-sending-data)