# Running curl -X PUT with json which is located in separate file

Tags: linux, curl, elasticsearch

I want to create a new template in Elastic search with a json file which located in /root directory.

I run the following:

```
curl -X PUT 'localhost:9200/_template/template_1?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d /root/myjson
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes
```

What is the correct way to send curl command with data that is placed in specific file?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving appears to be an ElasticSearch response, not a CURL error.

Based on this example, I would suspect that the issue may be malformed JSON:

[ElasticSearch error while sending data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213472/elasticsearch-error-while-sending-data)

You could try sending the data directly on the commandline, to see if you receive the same error, and then run your file contents through a JSON validator