# 405 Error when trying to use the Send Message API endpoint

Tags: python, api, kommunicate

I'm using Python's request package with the following code:

```
APIKEY = "XXX"
url = 'https://services.kommunicate.io/rest/ws/message/v2/send HTTP/1.1'

myobj = {
    'groupId': "xxx",
    'message':'Hello',
    "fromUserName":'yyy'
        }

headers = {
    'Api-Key':APIKEY,
}
response = requests.post(url, data = myobj,headers=headers)
```

And is giving me the following error:

```
'{"status":"error","errorResponse":[{"errorCode":"AL-MA-01","description":"method not allowed","displayMessage":"Request method \\u0027POST\\u0027 not supported"}],"generatedAt":1591385905404}'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can't POST there. What acceptable http verbs are allowed for that URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few issues with the code. 
1. `HTTP/1.1` is not part of the URL.
2. In `requests` package, in order to pass a JSON to server, there are multiple ways to do.

a. Use `json` parameter provided in `requests.post` method for sending JSON data to the server, something like below code:

```py
import requests

APIKEY = "XXX"
url = 'https://services.kommunicate.io/rest/ws/message/v2/send'
myobj = {
    'groupId': "xxx",
    'message': 'Hello',
    "fromUserName": 'yyy'
}

headers = {'Api-Key': APIKEY}

response = requests.post(url, json=myobj, headers=headers)
```

b. In Headers add `"Content-Type": "application/json"` and then first dump json data to string and then send it to server.

```py
import requests
import json 

APIKEY = "XXX"
url = 'https://services.kommunicate.io/rest/ws/message/v2/send'
myobj = {
    'groupId': "xxx",
    'message': 'Hello',
    "fromUserName": 'yyy'
}

headers = {
    'Api-Key': APIKEY,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

myobj = json.dumps(myobj)

response = requests.post(url, data=myobj, headers=headers)
```

Also, Do check [Difference between data and json parameters in python requests package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685248/difference-between-data-and-json-parameters-in-python-requests-package)