# Python / Requests - Can't send POST properly, despite it is working in Postman

Tags: python, python-requests, postman

everyone.
I have following code:

```
url = "url"
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

bot = telebot.TeleBot('xxx')



@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.chat.id)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.chat.username)
    data = {"userId": "message.chat.username", "chatId": "message.chat.id"}
    answer = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
    print(answer)
```

Answer is 400.
But when I use Postman with raw JSON:
{"userId":"xxx", "chatId": "xxx"}

It gives me 200.

Can't understand the difference. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to use `answer = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)` instead of your current code? Also don't forget to `import json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe problem with data. No?

```
data = {"userId": f"{message.chat.username}", "chatId": f"{message.chat.id}"}
```

instead of

```
data = {"userId": "message.chat.username", "chatId": "message.chat.id"}
```

Comment: Good catch, I actually didn't notice that on the first glance.

Answer (score 1):

For the postman, it already has a feature to generate code for any programming language you just need to click the code button and you will get the code.

[image]

you just click on the code button right side of the image

Answer (score 1):

Use `json` parameter instead of `data`. Note, that they are not the same: [Difference between data and json parameters in python requests package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685248/difference-between-data-and-json-parameters-in-python-requests-package).

```py
answer = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
```