# Sending Post request to Flask restAPI using python give response Error 500

Tags: python, api, rest, flask

Using Flask=1.1.1 on ubuntu 18.04

I've built a restAPI that serves machine learning model. After running the code I've tested using Postman and it works fine. I want to replicated this behavior in python because I want to do a stress test by sending multiple requests in a sequential manner.

After running flask app this is hosted on `http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict`

Using Python request module I sent post request like follows (using jupyter notebook on same machine that server is being hosted on):

```
data = {"A":123, "B":22, etc...}
url_path = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict'
response = requests.post(url_path, json.dumps(data))
response

>>> <Response [500]>
```

EDIT: sending data w/o json.dumps() outputs same Response[500]

my flask app's predict looks something like this:

```
@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    data = request.get_json()
    print(data)
```

printing data (what I send) is shown as `None`

I tried searching for how to test restAPI using python however had no luck finding it. I am new to restAPI and not sure of search words, if this seems obvious link to helpful resources would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try sending the `data` variable instead of using `json.dumps()`? So, `response = requests.post(url_path, data)`.

Comment: oh yes I've tried it however outputs same error code 500

Comment: Oh, thought of something else: do you have a valid `return` statement at the end of that route?

Comment: Yes I do, it returns `return jsonify({"pred":"success", "prediction":prediction})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you forgot to add **request** parameter to `predict` method

```py
import json

@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    data = json.loads(request.get_data())
    print(data)
```

#### Explanation:

In your client code you are not sending json, you are sending data. I cannot explain very well de difference but in order to receive json and have content in `request.get_json()` you must update your client to:

```py
data = {"A":123, "B":22, etc...}
url_path = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict'
response = requests.post(url_path, json=json.dumps(data))
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26685359/11972800) will give to you more detail about whats happens

Comment: How come it works in postman w/o it? Also adding it outputs `TypeError: predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'`

Comment: Sorry for the wrong answer. I edited it to make data available in flask correctly. Also remeber to return something like `jsonify(), 200` to prevent exception.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain or give link that explains why it didn't work before even though it worked in postman?

Comment: There I updated. :)