# Error getting async data from Solis Pro (Ginlong) plataform with payload

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm developing a web scraper to mine data from the Solis Pro platform (Ginlong), but I'm having problems getting the asynchronous data from the plants registered by the user. I'm using Selenium + bs4 and the following has happened.
The url is https://m.ginlong.com/pro/epc/plantview/view/doAsyncPlantList.json. I send a payload and in theory I should receive the data, but I am either receiving an error or only part of the data (only {status: 1}).

[Plataform and payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAyhU.png)

```
url = 'https://m.ginlong.com/'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  
webdriver = Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)
    
webdriver.get(url+'login.html')
webdriver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@ng-click="typeChange()"]').click()
webdriver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys(username)
webdriver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(password)

#webdriver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@class="close close-ico tra-fast"]').click()
webdriver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@id="login"]').click()
soup = BeautifulSoup(webdriver.page_source, 'lxml')

headers = {
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "accept": "application/json",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Mobile Safari/537.36"
}

postData = {
   "plantArray": [{"plantId":1033610,"timezoneId":24,"updateTime":"2022-01-18"},{"plantId":1028383,"timezoneId":24,"updateTime":"2022-01-18"}]
}

response = webdriver.request('POST', url+'pro/epc/plantview/view/doAsyncPlantList.json', headers=headers, data=postData)

if response.status_code != 200:
    raise RuntimeError("A requisição falhou: %s", response)

data = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
print(data.text)
```

The error that I'm getting

```
Exception: Unrecognized token 'plantId': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: plantId,timezoneId,updateTime,plantId,timezoneId,updateTime; line: 1, column: 8]

    com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'plantId': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: plantId,timezoneId,updateTime,plantId,timezoneId,updateTime; line: 1, column: 8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1702)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:558)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2836)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1899)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:749)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3847)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3792)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2835)
    at com.igen.solarman.controller.epc.PlantViewController.doAsyncPlantList(PlantViewController.java:345)
    at com.igen.solarman.controller.epc.PlantViewController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$70060edf.invoke()
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at com.igen.solarman.controller.epc.PlantViewController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b39c8e9a.doAsyncPlantList()
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1121.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.alibaba.druid.support.http.WebStatFilter.doFilter(WebStatFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21V8g.png)

Has anyone tried to get this data or know how I can resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change: `response = webdriver.request('POST', url+'pro/epc/plantview/view/doAsyncPlantList.json', headers=headers, data=postData)`

to this: `response = webdriver.request('POST', url+'pro/epc/plantview/view/doAsyncPlantList.json', headers=headers, json=json.dumps(postData))`

(remember to import json) :)

I am not sure why this works but it does, for further reading see this discussion about the difference between `data=` and `json=` : [Difference between data and json parameters in python requests package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685248/difference-between-data-and-json-parameters-in-python-requests-package)

Also, I've managed to get it work with requests only which should speed things up, note that I've had to change my url at the end to "cpro" not "pro" like yours since I don't have a pro account: "https://m.ginlong.com/pro/epc/plantview/view/doAsyncPlantList.json"

```
import requests
import json

s = requests.Session()

headers =   {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://m.ginlong.com/login.html'

resp = s.get(url,headers=headers)
print(resp)

login_url = 'https://m.ginlong.com/cpro/login/validateLogin.json'
payload = {
    'userName':'username',
    'userNameDisplay':'username',
    'password':'password',
    'lan':'2',
    'domain':'m.ginlong.com',
    'userType':'C'
    }

headers = {
    'accept':'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'accept-encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
    'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'origin':'https://m.ginlong.com',
    'referer':'https://m.ginlong.com/login.html',
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36'
    }

login = s.post(login_url,headers=headers,data=payload)
print(login)

new_plant_payload = {
    'name':'new_plant_2',
    'nmi':'',
    'type':'2',
    'gridType':'1',
    'searchInput':'',
    'positionAddressInput':'ChinaJiang Su ShengWu Xi ShiXin Wu QuTian An Zhi Hui Cheng A2',
    'rectangle':'120.36118,31.5065;',
    'lon':'120.36118',
    'lat':'31.5065',
    'address':'ChinaJiang Su ShengWu Xi ShiXin Wu QuTian An Zhi Hui Cheng A2',
    'country':'Jiang Su Sheng',
    'state':'Wu Xi Shi',
    'city':'Xin Wu Qu',
    'district':'Tian An Zhi Hui Cheng A2',
    'countryId':'44',
    'stateId':'',
    'cityId':'',
    'districtId':'',
    'power':'5.00',
    'timezoneId':'34',
    'direction':'180°',
    'angle':'26°',
    'currencyId':'19',
    'benchmarkPrice':'1.372',
    'price':'0.75',
    'priceNet':'1',
    'subsidy':'0.372',
    'subsidyYears':'20',
    'subsidyLocal':'0',
    'subsidyLocalYears':'0',
    'subsidyCity':'0',
    'subsidyCityYears':'0',
    'subsidyCounty':'0',
    'subsidyCountyYears':'0',
    'cost':'37500.00',
    'subsidyBuild':'1000',
    'percent':'0%',
    'interest':'0',
    'years':'',
    'repay':'1',
    'phone':''
    }

create_plant_headers = {
    'accept':'application/json',
    'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36'
    }

create_url = 'https://m.ginlong.com/cpro/epc/plantCreate/create/doSubmitPlant.json'

create = s.post(create_url,headers=create_plant_headers,data=new_plant_payload)
print(create)
print(create.text)

plant_id = create.json()['result']

async_url = 'https://m.ginlong.com/cpro/epc/plantview/view/doAsyncPlantList.json'
postData = {
   "plantArray": [{"plantId":plant_id,"timezoneId":24,"updateTime":"2022-01-18"}]
}
post_async = s.post(async_url,json=json.dumps(postData))

print(post_async)
print(post_async.text)
```

Comment: With the json=json.dumps(postData) I get {"state":1} as a result, but not the asynchronous data from the plants :(

Comment: In your version, I'm getting <Response [200]> <Response [200]> <Response [200]>
{"result":1508687,"state":1} <Response [200]> {"state":1}. Did you get the plant data besides the json with the status?

Comment: No I didn't, I assumed that because I don't have a pro version that's all I'd get. Did you change the url to "pro" instead of cpro and did you use your "plantArray"?

Comment: Yes, I did. Unfortunately, I still get only {"status": 1} instead of {"result":[{"date":"2022-01-18","dates":[{"bt":0,"date ":"1642496400000","minllis":-180,"power":20.0},{"bt":0,"date":"1642500900000","minllis":-180,"power":490.0},{ "bt":0,"date":"1642544700000","minllis":-180,"power":7.0907}, ...],
"plantId":1028383}], "state":1}, which would be the asynchronous data returned

Comment: Got it working?

Comment: I finally got the data, but using a different URL. I don't understand why I can't get this data through this URL, but using https://m.ginlong.com/pro/epc/plantDetail/showCharts.json which shows the same data I was able to get it to work