# Error in POST API python while trying to send data

Tags: python, post

Here is the json data to send

```
{
  "mobile": "1234567890"
}
```

Here is the python code:

```
from urllib import response
import requests
import urllib 
import json 

query = {"mobile": "1234567890"}
headers =  {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
url = 'https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/auth/public/generateOTP'
y = requests.post(url, data=query, headers=headers)

print(y)
```

Response from the API:

```
c:/pythonprojects/covid-otp-requests.py
<Response [400]>
```

I am a newbie, I don't understand the mistake I am making, Can someone please help me out?.

Comment: try `y = requests.post(url, json=query, headers=headers)`

Answer (score 0):

Fix here:

```
from urllib import response
import requests
import urllib 
import json 

params = {
    "mobile": "1234567890"
}
headers =  {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
response = requests.post("https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/auth/public/generateOTP", data=json.dumps(params))
print(response)

details = response.json()

print(details)
```

The parameters has to be sent in json format which I making a mistake in.

Thank you all!

Comment: As mentioned in the comment, if you pass argument `json` it will convert it for you. And if you want to keep using `data`, just make params str e.g. `params = '{"mobile": "917873731239"
}'`. check https://stackoverflow.com/q/26685248/4046632

Comment: @buran thankyou!