# calling an api with requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to call a private api endpoint with `requests.post`. The api doc says things that I don't understand and ain't able to make it work. So I was hoping If could find a solution here. Thanks

here's my code:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import requests
from hmac import new
from hashlib import sha256
from time import time
import os

load_dotenv()

key, secret = os.environ.get('KEY'), os.environ.get('SECRET')

data = {"request_id":f"{time()}".replace(".","")}

payload = {}
payload['url'] = "https://api.dex-trade.com/v1/private/orders"
payload['data'] = data

sign = new(secret.encode('utf-8'), f"{data['request_id']}".encode('utf-8'), sha256)

payload['headers'] = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'login-token': key,
    'x-auth-sign': sign.hexdigest()
}

r = requests.post(**payload)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

the api I'm trying to call is for a broker's website named 'dex-trade'. whenever I run the program I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: Can you share a link to the API Doc, i found a few diff wines online.

Comment: here's the [API Doc](https://docs.dex-trade.com/)

Comment: instead of `payload['data']`, try `payload['json']`. Or make the value for `data` key a str.

Comment: @buran thank you for your instruction. it started working all of a sudden after what you said.

Comment: It's not sudden - check https://stackoverflow.com/q/26685248/4046632

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between data and json parameters in python requests package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685248/difference-between-data-and-json-parameters-in-python-requests-package)