# How can I make request for an API?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm trying to make request for API: `https://thegraph.com/hosted-service/subgraph/uniswap/uniswap-v2` but I haven't ideas for this. My code gives me next ouput: `Response <400>` How can I fix it?

My code:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

def uniswap():
    url = "https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/uniswap/uniswap-v2"
    data = {
        'pairs': [
            "id",
            "reserve" : {
                "name",
                "symbol"
            }
        ]
    }
    r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
    print(r)

def main():
    uniswap()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Link for site:

```
https://thegraph.com/hosted-service/subgraph/uniswap/uniswap-v2
```

Comment: try `r = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between data and json parameters in python requests package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685248/difference-between-data-and-json-parameters-in-python-requests-package)

Comment: No, I think my programs are incorrect

Comment: Certainly this is one of the problems. Then there are 2 different urls in your question - check which one you need to use. Also is there any authentication required?

Comment: The `data` value posted is a syntax error.  `pairs` is a list, but `reserve` is a dictionary key.

Comment: authentication is not required. Yeah, I have to links one of list is for website doc and the next one is API. API link https://thegraph.com/hosted-service/subgraph/uniswap/uniswap-v2

Comment: Make sure your example code reproduces the problem.