# Unable to send request to localhost

Tags: python, python-requests, request

I was working with a local server when I encountered an error. It is a simple JSON string that I would like to send to the server. Although the string was successfully retrieved by the server, it ended up with an error in the code where the request was sent.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 449, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 444, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1371, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File ...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 319, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 301, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
http.client.BadStatusLine: Test

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send      
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 550, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 769, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 449, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 444, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1371, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 319, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 301, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('Test'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\Runner.py", line 14, in <module>
    r = requests.post(
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 117, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 529, in request   
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 645, in send      
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 501, in send      
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('Test'))
```

Code requests:

import requests

header = {
'Content-Type': "application/json"
}

content ={
"ID": "tyhsb12"
}
r = requests.post(
"http://192.168.43.211:8080/",
headers=header,
json= content
)
print(r.text)

Server Code:

```
import webbrowser
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class helloHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):


    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('content-type', 'application/json')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes(str("Test"), "utf-8"))

    def do_POST(self):
       self.send_response(200)
       self.send_header('content-type', "application/json")
       self.end_headers
       content_len = int(self.headers.get('content-length', 0))
       post_body = self.rfile.read(content_len,)
       post_body2 = post_body.decode('utf-8')
       print(post_body2)
       self.wfile.write(bytes(str("Test"), "utf-8"))


def main():
    PORT = 8080
    server = HTTPServer(('192.168.43.211', PORT), helloHandler)
    print("Server Started " + str(PORT))
    webbrowser.open("http://192.168.43.211:" + str(PORT) + "/" )
    server.serve_forever()

   


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Don't use `Content-Type` header if you use parameter `json`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between data and json parameters in python requests package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685248/difference-between-data-and-json-parameters-in-python-requests-package)

Comment: Problem persists. Doesn't work.

Comment: Where does the error happen?  In the sending code, or the receiving code?

Comment: @JohnGordon In sending JSON to server.

Answer (score 0):

### just edit one line:

```
import requests

header = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json"
}

content ={
    "ID": "tyhsb12"
}
r = requests.post(
    "http://192.168.43.211:8080/",
    headers=header,
    data= content #    <===; edit this line (use "data=" instead of "json=")
)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Why is this a fix? Add any relevant documentation

Comment: @AbhinavMathue just try it && Documentation: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request

Comment: Problem persists. Doesn't work.

Comment: try removing 'Content-Type' header

Comment: @ibrahem Still same thing. Is it happing because I am using a not secure server like HTTP except HTTPS?

Comment: @ibrahem I am uploading the code now. Could you please also test it out for yourself?

Comment: I think your server.py does not follow HTTP POST protocol

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ibrahemesam/796851a43c0d189adb2051f866993a93

Comment: @ibrahem I already added. However, I have no idea what the issue is.

Comment: @ibrahem If I sent a request with CURL. It works fine without error.

Comment: then you should convert that curl command to python with this tool: https://curlconverter.com/