# Not able to call post method using python requests library when using headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am new to Python. I am using 'requests' library to send post request. I am able to send post request without headers but when giving headers I am getting HTTP 400 error.

```
import requests

API_ENDPOINT = "https://reqres.in/api/users"

data = {"name": "Name1", "job": "job1"}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

# sending post request and saving response as response object
full_output = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, headers=headers,  data = data)
print("response status", full_output.status_code)
print("response", full_output.text)
```

**Output:**

```
response status 400

response <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Bad Request</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

It is working if I pass empty headers in the code

```
headers = {}
```

Not sure why it is not working. Request your help. Thanks.

Comment: try `json=data` or you need to dump your `data` dict to JSON first before if you use that json string with `data=`. Note that `json=data` will set the headers `Content-Type` for you, so you can skip that as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between data and json parameters in python requests package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685248/difference-between-data-and-json-parameters-in-python-requests-package)

Comment: Hi @buran , yes after doing json=data it resolved my issue. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending python dict where the api is expecting json string, to which you need to encode your dict. You can go for either of them:

```
full_output = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, headers=headers,  data = json.dumps(data))

full_output = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, json = data)
```

Comment: I have tried with the first one and it is working. Thanks.

Comment: With 2nd approach, you don't have to set the content-type explicitly as it automatically sets Content-Type header to application/json, and also encodes the data to json

Comment: yes but I think I cannot use 2nd approach as I might have other headers as well apart from Content-Type. Say auth header, some custom header etc. I need to pass those headers.